# Using rails associations when using multiple columns to establish the relationship (i.e. model_name and model_id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have three models, User, Institute, and File. The idea is that a user or an institute can both have many unique files. However, I am not sure how to set up the associations between them correctly. What I want to be able to happen is to have @user.files and @institute.files return the list of files associated with that user/institute , i.e.:

```
@user.files = File.where("belongs_to_id = ? AND belongs_to_class = ?", @user.id, "User")
```

I don't want to add a references to user and institute (although that would work), so if I ever want to add a new model that can also have multiple files, I don't have to modify that table. I could use my own method to return the files, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it using associations directly?

Thanks,

```
class File
    attr_accessible :belongs_to_class, :belongs_to_id
    belongs_to :institute
    belongs_to :user
end

class User
    has_many :files
end

class Institute
    has_many :files
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the correct way to do it was to use polymorphism:

Migration:

```
class CreateFiles
    def change
        create_table :files do |t|
            t.references :owner, :polymorphic => true, :index => true, :null => false
        end
    end
end
```

Models:

```
class File
    #  owner_id            :integer          not null
    #  owner_type          :string(255)      not null
    belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
end

class User
    has_many :files, :as => :owner, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Institute
    has_many :files, :as => :owner, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

This allows me to get all the files associated with any of the models, using the standard: model.files.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to associate all 3 models & to User & institute are connected to file model by has-many association :

```
   class User
      has_many :files
    end

    class Institute
      has_many :files
    end

    class File
      belongs_to :institute
      belongs_to :user
    end


    files table should hold columns like: 
    name:string user_id:integer institute_id:integer 

    Here you can fetch files as : 

    User.first.files 
    Institute.first.files
```

Comment: There isn't neccessarily a relationship between the user and the institute, and a file can belong only either to a User OR to an Institute. I CAN do it the way you mention (i.e. having separate user_id and institute_id). However, I want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: This is the rails way you should follow @Hawkeye001 . In this way, you can call the objects directly through association. By Writing raw queries this goal can be  achieved but that's again not the standard way. :)

Comment: Ajay, I figured the right way to do it was to use polymorphism (see my answer for details). The method you mentioned while it would give the desired end results, doesn't really seem like the correct way to do it since if i had 10 models, all who had files, your way would mean i would need 10 columns in my files table to support that, which doesn't really seem right. Using polymorphism, only an owner id and type are required, and through that i associated the models.